# Swapping contents of an array of unequal columns

Tags: arrays

I have this question and so far I was able to create a method to sum the values of integers in a row and compare it with the sum of the other row, but I don't know how to swap the rows. Any help?

The question is:

Write a Java program that given a two-dimensional array, reorders the rows such that the row with the highest row sum is the first row.

If the program will be called with the following array:

```
1 3 5 9
2 100
2 2 3
```

then the output should be:

```
2 100
1 3 5 9
2 2 3
```

The following steps should be performed:

1. calculate row sum
2. Find index of row with maximum sum
3. Swap row of maximum sum with row 0

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int [][] a = {{1,3,5,9},{2,100},{2,2,3}};
    int max = sum(0,a);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if( max < sum(i,a) )
        {
            max = sum (i,a);
            index = i;
        }
    }
}

public static int sum(int y, int[][]x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<x[y].length; j++)
        sum+= x[y][j];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What kind of language - Java?

Comment: @splash58 Yes, Java.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my insolence, I have never written in Java and I cann't try - haven't an tool, but I think, that the code should look something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int [][] a = {{1,3,5,9},{2,100},{2,2,3}};
    int max = sum(a[0]);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        int t = sum(a[i]);
        if( max < t )
        {
            max = t;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if (index != 0) {
       int tmp[] = a[0];
       a[0] = a[index];
       a[index] = tmp; 
    }
}

public static int sum(int[]x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<x.length; j++)
        sum+= x[j];
    return sum;
}
```